# Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de reducir este if en java

Tags: java, condiciones

E hecho este codigo para saber si el grado introducido existe en la interface general grade existe pero quiero saber si se puede reducir el if del errorGrade

```
public class Student implements DataGeneral, ErrorDataGeneral, ErrorLenghtData, ErrorGrade, GeneralGrade{
public Student(String gradeStudent) {

        
        this.gradeStudent = gradeStudent;
    }
@Override
    public void errorGrade() throws GradeException {

        if (!(GeneralGrade.GRADE_CUARTO.equals(gradeStudent) || GeneralGrade.GRADE_DECIMO.equals(gradeStudent)
                || GeneralGrade.GRADE_KINDER.equals(gradeStudent) || GeneralGrade.GRADE_NOVENO.equals(gradeStudent)
                || GeneralGrade.GRADE_OCTAVO.equals(gradeStudent) || GeneralGrade.GRADE_ONCE.equals(gradeStudent)
                || GeneralGrade.GRADE_PRIMERO.equals(gradeStudent) || GeneralGrade.GRADE_QUINTO.equals(gradeStudent)
                || GeneralGrade.GRADE_SEGUNDO.equals(gradeStudent) || GeneralGrade.GRADE_SEPTIMO.equals(gradeStudent)
                || GeneralGrade.GRADE_SEXTO.equals(gradeStudent) || GeneralGrade.GRADE_TERCERO.equals(gradeStudent)
                || GeneralGrade.GRADE_TRANSICION.equals(gradeStudent))) {

            throw new GradeException("El grado en el que estas no esta disponible");

        }

    }

private String gradeStudent = "";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todavía se puede optimizar más si utilizas un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) para guardar tus grados, esta clase tiene el método [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) que te ayudaría a encontrar si existe el elemento o no más fácilmente

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> grades = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList("CUARTO", "DECIMO", "KINDER", "NOVENO", "OCTAVO",
                "ONCE", "PRIMERO", "QUINTO", "SEGUNDO", "SEPTIMO", "SEXTO",
                "TERCERO", "TRANSICION")
        );
        String search = "PRIMERO";
        if(grades.contains(search))
            System.out.println("Existe " + search);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es lo que buscas, pero puedes usar un Array, dónde meter todos los grados, y luego con un for, comparar si el grado recibido por parámetro, existe o no existe.

Hice un ejemplo sencillo en el método main para que veas lo que quiero decir

```java
public class CompararIf {
    
    public static void main(String[] srgs){

        String gradeStuden = "GRADE_TRANSICION";
        String grade = "";
        String[] grados = {"GRADE_CUARTO", "GRADE_DECIMO", "GRADE_KINDER", "GRADE_NOVENO", "GRADE_OCTAVO",
            "GRADE_ONCE", "GRADE_PRIMERO", "GRADE_QUINTO", "GRADE_SEGUNDO", "GRADE_SEPTIMO", "GRADE_SEXTO", 
            "GRADE_TERCERO", "GRADE_TRANSICION"};
    
        for (int i = 0; i < grados.length; i++){
             if (! grados[i].equals(gradeStudent)){
                 grade = grados[i];
             }
        }
        System.out.println("El grade " + grade + " está disponible");
    }
}
```